# GEE export pixel coordinates

Tags: google-earth-engine, coordinates, pixel

I'm trying to add the pixel coordinates (latitude and longitude) as bands to export (code below). However, the export returns 1 decimal place for the latitude and longitude. How can I increase the precision (# decimals) in my export for the coordinates?

```
//function to add coordinates
var getLatLong = (function(img) {

  var proj = img.select([0]).projection()
  // get coordinates image
 var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().reproject(proj)
 var img1 = img.addBands(latlon.select('longitude','latitude'))



  return img1;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I just need to lose the 'reproject'

```
 var getLatLong = (function(img) {

  // Get the projection
  var proj = img.select([0]).projection()
  // get coordinates image
 var latlon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat()//.reproject(proj)
 var img1 = img.addBands(latlon.select('longitude','latitude'))



  return img1;
});
```

Comment: If your problem is solved, please mark this as answer.